# Как назвать устройство для эвтаназии?

Tags: грамотная-речь, названия

Для подготовки проб для биохимических исследований рыб надо быстро убить, так как длительная агония существенно изменяет содержание гормонов.
Мы сделали устройство для эвтаназии рыб. Как его правильно назвать: эвтанатор, эвтанизатор, эвтанайзер или еще как-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На другом сайте уже дали реально полезный ответ.
При выборе названия для устройства, важно учесть научную точность и этические соображения. В данном случае, я бы рекомендовал использовать термин "эвтанатор", так как он более точно описывает процесс эвтаназии. Это слово объединяет "эвтаназию" (это процесс гуманного усыпления или убийства животных для научных целей) и суффикс "-атор", указывающий на устройство или инструмент, выполняющий определенное действие. Эвтанизатор и эвтанайзер могут восприниматься как название профессий.
А это рисунок эвтанатора. https://cloud.mail.ru/public/AV8C/vdEeQVuZP
Спасибо всем, кто не использовал этот вопрос для грязных инсинуаций.

Comment: Гуманным убийство быть не может по определению гуманности. Любое убийство антигуманно.

Comment: Василий, плюс от меня. Присоединяюсь к вашему ответу.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, слова "эвтаназия" нет в законах об обращении с животными, а во-вторых есть только запрет [эвтаназии людей](https://medkarabash74.ru/obschie-svedeniya/dokumenty/fz-no323-ot-21-11.2011/ob-osnovah-ohrany-zdorovya-grazhdan-rf#:%7E:text=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%8D%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%2D%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%20(%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC)%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0.,), так что любое причинение смерти животным, должно бы жестко [регламентировано](https://crimea.ria.ru/20230518/evtanazii-ne-budet-chto-menyaetsya-v-zakone-o-zhivotnykh-1128803018.html) и не содержать несуществующих понятий, просто так ненужную тварь убить нельзя. Так что немного странно, что вы хотите его реализовывать в РФ. Убийство лабораторных животных, которые перестали быть полезны априори находится вне закона. А любой прибор называющийся "эвтанатор" или подобно, может юридически быть расценен как инструмент для реализации эвтаназии людей, которая запрещена, потому что какой-то иной эвтаназии в законе РФ нет.

**Поэтому такого "устройства" в легальном пространстве РФ в принципе не должно быть.**

Важное:

Дело в том, что вопрос эвтаназии очень мутный даже в рамках семантических изысков. Убийство есть убийство, но убийство врага или вредителя мы будем называть уничтожением. В новостях можно услышать, что были "уничтожены скопления живой силы противника...", есть средства для "уничтожения вредителей", тут убийство "оправдано" потенциальной опасностью со стороны животного или человека. С другой стороны рыбаки, заводчики могут заниматься ловлей или заготовкой для пропитания - то есть для пользы, а не во вред.

Однако, когда дело касается не кого-то опасного, а просто уже ненужного, уже неудобного - лишнего, а с другой стороны это убийство и пользы не приносит; когда это убийство животного, которое было полезно, а теперь вдруг уже не полезно и давайте его убьем, то есть усыпим... Нет погодите, это ваша тварь, вы несете за неё ответственность, она вам служила верой и правдой в лаборатории: платила своим здоровьем в ходе экспериментов над ней, - **эта тварь - друг, а вы ей платите злом за добро?**

*Вот на этом циничном моменте начинается деструкция моральных ценностей, в том числе и общечеловеческих, гуманистических*.

А дальше будет пропасть беззакония и анархия, ведь вся гуманистическая мораль держится на позитивном нравственном принципе "поступай с другими так, как хочешь чтобы поступали с тобой - твори добро". **Предлагающие легализовать эвтаназию в любой форме, заигрывающие с легализацией "легкой смерти", легализуют тем самым нарушение ЗПМ со своей стороны: ты будешь поступать, как хочешь, чтобы поступали с тобой, то есть приносить нам пользу, а мы тебя убьём, когда ты перестанешь быть полезен просто потому, что твоя смерть даст нам облегчение.**

*Всё.*

*Дальше миф о "добром мире" перестает существовать, так как негласный договор о гуманности отношений нарушен легализацией договора "легкой смерти".*

**Поэтому никакой иной позиции человек считающий себя гуманистом по вопросу эвтаназии иметь не может, а если он начинает рассуждать в ином ключе, то этот человек не гуманист, а существо иного рода или вида.**

Comment: Вы отвечайте по существу. Зачем писать трактаты, в которых не содержится ответа на вопрос.

Comment: @Серж по существу о чём? прибора для "гуманного убийства животных" в законодательстве РФ не предусмотрено, если бы это было устройство для забоя - это другой разговор, но на данным момент это разговор о какой-то противоправной деятельности.

Comment: Ясное дело, что нет. Зачем писать про беззаконие, анархию, о добре и и т. д ? К чему эти морали? Целая лекция и ни о чем. Дальше читайте ответ Василия.

Comment: @Серж ну так он сам себе и ответил, но я не считаю что слова можно образовывать вразрез с ментальными факторами, основой которых в современном мире является гуманность. Язык - это лишь отражение внутреннего мира, если он начинает оказывать деструктивное воздействие на внутренний мир стоит задуматься над моральностью данного словотворчества. Кроме того в моём ответе были примеры переводов, но ответы Василию не понравились(так как отражали моральную делему, а на скрывали её), он пожаловался модератору и тот его удалил, поэтому я решил их заново не постить)

Comment: Знаете, по вашей логике, нужно убрать многие слова, т. к. они не отвечают морально-нравственным  принципам. Человеку важно было знать, какое название подходящее. Все остальное за пределами русского языка.

Comment: @Серж какие, например?

Comment: Любые, не отвечающие морально-нравственным принципам.

Comment: @Серж ответ лишенный конкретики - не ответ. Я же говорю, я дал ответ на вопрос, который отражал как и моральную пропасть в значении, так и суть слова, но Василию они не понравились и он пожаловался модератору. Так вот, я подумал: то о чем просит Василий есть попытка русифицировать термин "эвтаназия" который не слово совсем, хотя и имеет греческие корни, это слово новодел, несущий определенное значение, вполне конкретное, аморальное. Когда вы его проводите через правила русской грамматики,вы как бы проводите информационный вирус через иммунный барьер - русскоговорящие начинают считать его своим

Comment: @Серж прибор для эвтанации - лучше даже на латинском, так как слово не греческое, его придумали на западе как составное из греческих корней. Тогда читатель посмотрит, что есть эвтаназия, почитает, разберется, а не будет отталкиваться от уже якобы значений, которых нет и быть не может, так как вещь противозаконная и аморальная в корне.

Comment: @Серж такие слова - это бомбы замедленного действия. вы просто слишком наивно относитесь к языку, язык это не на заборе писать, это очень серьезный инструмент для моделирования сознания. Разрушьте смысловые связи между словами семантикой и у вас уже люди не понимают друг друга, так как каждый изъяснятся на профессиональном сленге. Язык - это инструмент, культурное оружие которое точно также как и масса других вещей используется в "гибридной войне". Так что ваше отношение к проблеме слишком легкомысленное. Есть, такой метод - расчеловечивание, который используется в пропаганде,

Comment: @Серж когда человека называют, свинья или нелюдь или орк или еще как, но не человек, не как другой человек будет называть себя, это делается специально потому что образуется связка на интуитивном уровне свой-чужой. Раз это не человек а гоблин, монстр, значит его можно убить не испытывая угрызений совести. Так что если вы увлекаетесь лингвистикой, советую задуматься не только о графомании и беллетристике, а то для чего люди вообще придумывают новые слов и придают новые значения этим словам. Подумайте о причинах языка и словотворчестве.

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю, как устроен язык. Я в отличии от вас изучал лингвистики в институте. Поэтому говорю: в вашем ответе одна вода, фантазия. Давайте не будет переходить за рамки лингвистики и языка в целом. Это сайт языка, а не философии. Вы пишете  о законе, о морали, о христианстве. Все ваши мысли запутано и несут никакой информации. Поэтому и ваш ответ удалили.

Comment: @Серж Опять же. Ответ не содержащий конкретику, а только номинативное постулирование: у меня диплом - поэтому я врач, - не является содержательным ответом.  Вам как лингвисту странно этого не знать. Касательно же эвтаназии - можно проще, данный предмет не имеет права существовать в языковом пространстве РФ так как нарушает нормы содержания животных и/или права людей. То есть это либо прямая пропаганда насилия в отношении животных или завуалированная угроза человеческой жизни - давайте закроем вопрос.

Comment: @Серж УК РФ Статья 282. Возбуждение ненависти либо вражды, а равно унижение человеческого достоинства. Эвтаназия упоминается только в запрете её в отношении людей. Тут рекламируют нейкий "прибор для эвтаназии", то есть это прибор для ...

Comment: Повторюсь: здесь отвечают на вопросы по русскому языку. Что где запрещено и отвечает ли аппарат морально-нравственным принципам - не наше дело.

Comment: @Серж поэтому в университете и проходят философию, не для галочки как бы, а в школе ограничиваются просто учебным пособием по обществознанию. И я уверен в твоем вузе также был курс хотя бы общей философии, должен был быть). И сейчас ты сам сужаешь область своих знаний и умений, до уровня функционала в словомарании или графомании - не знаю. Без философской базы, зачем ты это делаешь и какие принципы соблюдаешь - это не имеет никакого смысла, ты же не робот какой-то. То есть "здесь"(видимо имеется ввиду СЕ) имеет большее значение, чем твоё человеческое начало?

Comment: @Серж "не наше дело" - что вообще значит эта фраза? Я понимаю, ты за себя что-то решил, но тут ты меня как бы в одну лодку сажаешь). СЕ кстати соблюдает законы, только не РФ, а США

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/43700)

Comment: @IvanOlshansky зачем? я считаю ответ полным, свои примеры я добавлял, ответ с ними был удален, в виду что они могут вызывать негативные ощущения у читающий, поэтому я их убрал оставил только суть. Я не думаю что вопрос можно переформулировать каким-то иным образом, а желания обращаться к модераторам или ставить вопрос в очередь для проверок у меня нет.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky и вообще свои ответы я пишу для себя прежде всего, так как мне хочется закрепить мысли в какой-то форме. Ну и для задающего вопрос. Василий также понял мою позицию, хотя и не согласился - но это его дело.